# Check if termination is enabled for all EC2 AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a code which lists all ec2 instances in all regions

```
import boto3



client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')

ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
    instances = conn.instances.filter()
    for instance in instances:
        #if instance.state["Name"] == "running":
     print instance.id #   , instance.instance_type, region)
```

now, i want, for all instances, to check if termination protection is enabled or not

```
terminate_protection=client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId =instance.id,Attribute = 'disableApiTermination')
```

code above lists only instances from us-east-1 and if passed instanceID not from that region then it complains (instance not found)

How to pass instanceID to `describe_instance_attribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boto3 client object you've created as `client` is localised to the `us-east-1` region because that's what you specified with the `region_name` parameter.  You need to create a separate client for each region:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')  # Doesn't actually matter what region you use here
ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]

for region in ec2_regions:
    # Need to create a new client per-region
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
    instances = conn.instances.filter()
    for instance in instances:
        print instance.id #   , instance.instance_type, region)
        # Now we can get the termination state
        terminate_protection=client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId =instance.id,Attribute = 'disableApiTermination')
```